# Coldfusion CreateDate Issue

Tags: coldfusion

I'm having some trouble with the `CreateDate()` function, it's just erroring and I have no idea why!

I am running this query to get all of the dates from news stories so that I can create a news archive monthly.

```
<cfquery name="selectNews" datasource="#Request.dsn#">
    SELECT Month(NewsDate) AS theCount
    FROM news
    GROUP BY Month(NewsDate)
</cfquery>
```

Then when I output it, I'm trying to output it in the following format

- Aug 2012
- Sept 2012
- Oct 2012

So I'm using the following code to try to output this list

```
<ul>
<cfloop query="selectNews">
    <cfoutput>
    <cfset theDay = DateFormat(Now(), 'dd')>
        <cfset theMon = theCount>
        <cfset theYear = DateFormat(Now(), 'yyyy')>
        <li>#CreateDate(theYear, theMon, theDay)#</li>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
</ul>
```

It works fine for the first item, it will output `Aug 2012`, however it will then error, saying this

```
Error Occurred While Processing Request
MONTH
```

Which to me, at least, is useless!

Comment: is this the exact code?  also qualify your query variables.  theMon = selectNews.theCount.  It won't fix your problem but don't be sloppy.

Comment: Use a cfdump to look at the query. I suspect your second row does not have a valid value being passed into month.

Comment: Why use group by if you're not doing an aggregate? Like Jason I suspect your query results aren't what you expect.

Comment: Nope, was me being an idiot. I was using `DateFormat(Now(), 'dd')`, which is a huge stupid mistake, seeing as there is only 30 days in September. It was running `CreateDate(2012, 09, 31)`, which obviously won't work. Maybe if the debug error was better I might've spotted that a bit earlier.

Comment: can't believe I didn't catch that myself. :) it would have worked yesterday!

Comment: Yeah well, you didn't spend the best part of half hour trying to figure this out! It'd work 30 days of 7 months of the year!

Comment: ColdFusion has a built in DaysInMonth() function that you can use if you need the last day of the month

Comment: @MattBusche, I didn't actually need the day, I just needed a day so I could use the Create Date function - I was just using the wrong day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was me being an idiot. I was using `DateFormat(Now(), 'dd')`, which is a huge stupid mistake, seeing as there is only 30 days in September. It was running `CreateDate(2012, 09, 31)`, which obviously won't work!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the [SQL Month()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) function is returning a 0 for January and [CreateDate](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_c-d_09.html) expects a 1 for January.

**Edit**

```
<ul>
<cfloop query="selectNews">

    <cfset theDay = Day(Now())>
    <cfset theMon = #theCount#>
    <cfset theYear = Year(Now())>
    <cfoutput><li>#DateFormat(CreateDate(theYear, theMon, theDay), "mmm yyyy")#</li></cfoutput>

</cfloop>
</ul>
```

**Edit**

This seems to be working but only with odd numbered months

```
<cfset months = [1,3,5] />
<ul>
    <cfloop array="#months#" index="currentmonth">

        <cfoutput><li>#DateFormat(CreateDate(Year(Now()), currentmonth, Day(Now())), "mmm yyyy")#</li></cfoutput>

    </cfloop>
</ul>
```

Comment: I thought so too, but when I output `theCount`, I get `8, 9, 10`, which corresponds to Aug, Sept and Oct.

Comment: @johnthenxiii, it wasn't even a coding error in the end, it was a stupid error based on me being an idiot. See comment on original post. Thanks for the help though. +1.

Comment: <cfset the Mon = #theCount#> doesn't need the # signs. Macromedia indicated extra pound signs were a best practice no no years ago.

Comment: @Travis, it was copy paste. See the question before the edit.

Comment: @both - yeah, that was my bad. I'm not normally so bad practice, I promise!