# CreateDate issue in ColdFusion / CFWheels

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfwheels

I am trying to use CreateDate in CFWheels and I am getting stupid errors that I will explain in detail in  sec.

To start, this is my code

```
<cfscript>
            lastM = dateFormat(CreateDate(year(now()),month(now())-1,day(now())),'MM');
            d = DaysInMonth(lastM);
            session.start = dateFormat(CreateDate(Year(rightnow),Month(lastM),Day(01)),'YYYY-MM-DD');
            session.end = dateFormat(CreateDate(Year(rightnow),Month(lastM),Day(d)),'YYYY-MM-DD');
            session.date = "last_month";
</cfscript>
```

As you can see I am trying to set my session variables `start` and `end` to the beginning and end of 'last month'. When I dump `lastM` and `d` I am getting correct values for the month and the DaysInMonth. When I use these two variables in my `CreateDate` method the `session.start` is becoming equal to 2013-01-31 and `session.end` is equal to 2013-01-30. I tried writing the method in many different ways  but I don't see what is causing this.

I have already checked this issue [Coldfusion CreateDate Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157243/coldfusion-createdate-issue) here but it is not the same with what I am experiencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misusing the `month()` function. [From the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6dcf.html):

> Extracts the month value from a *date/time object*

You are passing in a number, which CF implicitly converts to *a date* (probably 01/03/1900), just not the correct one. So `month()` is actually returning `1`. That is why your results say January 2013.

A simpler way to accomplish this is to use `dateAdd`. Simply calculate the first of the current month. Then subtract months or days to get the start and end of the previous month. (Note: I would leave the values as date objects and only "format" them when you need to display them to the user).

```
<cfscript>
    today = now();
    firstOfThisMonth = CreateDate( year(today), month(today), 1);
    firstOfLastMonth = dateAdd("m", -1, firstOfThisMonth);
    endOfLastMonth = dateAdd("d", -1, firstOfThisMonth);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Thanks Leigh. This was also causing a 'Month' error because it was setting April to have 31 days instead of 30.

Comment: Yep, that is why it is better to use date functions than to roll your own. Date functions take care of the nitty-gritty details for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove your day functions from the last arguments of createDate. Just use `1` and `d`.

Comment: And that was something that I did before posting the question but it did not work